# Angularjs1.x Directive Prelink/Postlink/link function difference?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was trying to understand the angularjs directive prelink/postlink function in many tutorial, but not able to identify whether the normal link function , is it equivalent to a pre link or a post link function.

```
(1) 

link : function(scope element, attrs) {

} 

(2)

pre : function(scope element, attrs) {

} 

(3)

post : function(scope element, attrs) {

}
```

***"Is (1) equal to (2) || (1) equal to (3)" ??***

Answer (score 0):

After going through so many blogs and tutorials , finally got my answer [here](https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/07/07/practical-guide-to-prelink-postlink-and-controller-methods-of-angular-directives/)

For AngularJs, the **link function is a post-link function**. So in general we can write the post-link function in two ways:

(1) using object literal notation which has a post method link:

```
  link:{ post:function(scope,elem,attr)
    {
      // .....
    }
   }
```

(2) Simply set the link method.

```
link: function(scope,elem,attr){
       // ...      
      }
```